# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a pick up weapon system on unity using c#.
I'm trying to change a value from a script to another but I'm having some problems.
I'm trying to change the weapon number to 1.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pew : MonoBehaviour
{
public int weapon = 0;
}
```

So, I'm using this line of code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUpBow : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
    GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("ThePlayer");
    Pew pew = thePlayer.GetComponent<Pew>();
    pew.weapon = 1;
    }
}
```

But when I touch the object, it gives me the following error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity", on the following line: `Pew pew = thePlayer.GetComponent<Pew>();`

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the collision is with the player.

The problem is because GameObject.Find("ThePlayer") search the hierarchy for any game object named **exactly** that way. Maybe there is some blank space in the name. It is not a good practice to use that method because it may cause that kind of problems.

So, instead of:

```
GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("ThePlayer");
Pew pew = thePlayer.GetComponent<Pew>();
```

Be better like:

```
GameObject thePlayer = collision.gameObject;
Pew pew = thePlayer.GetComponent<Pew>();
```

The problem with this new code is that we assume the collision is with the player, but what if is an enemy?

A good solution is using [Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html), and now:

```
if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player") 
{
    GameObject thePlayer = collision.gameObject;
    Pew pew = thePlayer.GetComponent<Pew>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I was trying to fix this for 2 hours, you're the best. It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

That means `thePlayer` is `null`.

This means that the assignment did not work:
`GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("ThePlayer");`

make sure this works:
`GameObject.Find("ThePlayer");`

The docs:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

> This function only returns active GameObjects. If no GameObject with name can be found, null is returned.

Make sure the names match correctly!

Comment: If I'm trying to change a intager, how do I assign a GameObject?